# maven dependency war issue

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I wanted to exclude the following dependency from final war build(using mvn package/install).

Which scope is preferable?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If it's provided, it's provided--what's the issue?

Comment: Dave, I could still see it under generated war file. I used mvn clean install

Comment: @techie2k something else may transitively depend on it.

Comment: Have you used `mvn clean`?

Comment: Show the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, `provided` or `test`.  `provided` will exclude the jar from the classpath in your tests, too.  If you want to test code that depends on that dependency, you should use `test` instead.

If you still see this dependency in your war file after installing we'll need more information to debug.  It could be that you included this dependency more than once without realizing it.  It could also be that another dependency is transitively including this jar and you'll have to use the exclude tag to remove it.

Comment: Dependency Graph does not show duplicate.. anyway I will analyse the same

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target deploy server. If you're deploying on application server such as `Glassfish`, `Jboss` etc. with JSF libraries installed then `scope` ***provided*** is preferred. Or alternatively use exclusion to remove the dependency from your target war.

Alternatively, if you are deploying on a context server such as `tomcat`, `jetty` etc. remove scope target to copy the library across to avoid dependency issues.